# Python: Get the first "encountered" duplicated character in a string

Tags: python-3.x, big-o

I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to resolve the following coding test:

Problem: Get the first duplicate char ENCOUNTERED in a string only if more than one dup char is detected, else return None'

Examples:

#1 'abbcdefa' = return 'b' because it is the first encountered DUPLICATE character in the string, while the duplicate 'a' character appears much later than the duplicate 'b'.

#2 'abcdefa' = None (because a is the only dup char in the string)

```
def first_dup_char(A):
    seen, dups = [], []
    for i in A:
        if i in seen:
            dups.append(i)
        else:
            seen.append(i)
    # if dups list items > 1 then return the first dup else print None
    return dups[0] if len(dups) > 1 else 'None'
```

My solution above works by utiizing two lists.  I wanted to use set() and dict, but unfortunately both of them are unordered, unless I miss something?

Comment: "but unfortunately both of them are unordered" How is that relevant? For ``seen`` it does not matter if they are ordered, and if you just want *the first* duplicate you can stop once a single duplicate is found – there is no need to even store it.

Comment: Not that it would be matter here, but ``dict`` is insertion ordered since CPython/PyPy 3.6 and generally Python 3.7.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I use 'seen' and 'dups' ( both list type) to track found elements and duplicate elements separately.   I hope you saw that example #1  in the description (where string = 'abbcdefa ') in which  both 'a' and 'b' both have duplicates, HOWEVER,  the duplicate 'b' comes  first before the duplicate 'a', so the answer should be 'b'.

Comment: Just as @MisterMiyagi suggested earlier- you should look into `set` is much simpler to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a set to update with the letters you encounter while you loop through like this

```
def first_dup_char(A) :

    seen = set()
    first_dup = None 

    for c in A :
        if c in seen  : 
            if first_dup == None : first_dup = c
            else : return first_dup
        else :
            seen.add(c)
    
    return None

A = "abbcdefa"
print(first_dup_char(A)) # b
B = "abcdefa"
print(first_dup_char(B)) # None
```

using the variable `first_dup`  you don't lose the information on which one is the first duplicate and also you get to know when you already achieved two pairs of duplicates so that you can return the first one without running the loop till the end.

Comment: It works, but the logic can be simplified. Just put anything into `seen` first, then first char when we hit `seen` that must be the answer - first duplicates.

Comment: @DanielHao totally right, I have simplified it!

Comment: Should this be `seen.add(c)` instead?  and `first_dup is None`?

Comment: agree that it should be `seen.add(c)` instead of `seen.update(c)`.    @Tortar thank you for sharing this beautiful solution!    I suppose you choose the set() because doing `in` operator on a set() gives us O(1) while doing an `in` operator on a list gives us O(n),   and O(1) is better than O(n), right?

Comment: yes @punsoca that's the reason why you want to use sets with this operation, they are faster :D . Yes seen.add(c) is more appropriate even if seen.update(c) works as well